# A question on the curvature of a regular parametrized curve

Tags: differential-geometry

The next question is from Do-Carmo's baby book, page 30 question 3 in section 1-6.

The question goes as follows:
Show that the curvature $k(t)\neq 0$ of a regular parametrized curve $\alpha : I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is the curvature at $t$ of of the plane curve $\pi \circ \alpha$, where $\pi$ is the normal projection of $\alpha$ over the osculating plane at $t$.

Now I guess I don't understand what is $\pi$ here, I mean I have $$\alpha(s)= (x(s),y(s),z(s))$$ assume it's in arclength parametrization, so basically I want to show that:

$$(\pi \circ \alpha (s))'' = k \cdot n_{\pi \circ \alpha (s)}\;,$$

but I am not sure here what $\pi$ equals to, I mean if its a projection on the osculating plane which is the plane of $xy$ then shouldn't it be the binormal to $\alpha$ (in which case it's $(0,0,z(s))$)?

Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get the symbol for concatenation using `\circ`. To put punctuation on a line after a displayed equation (instead of at the beginning of the next line), you need to include it before the closing `$$` (preferably preceded by a `\;` to set it off from the equation).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use coordinates to built your intuition! Use them when you need to make calculations.

Given a point $\alpha(t)$ on our curve, consider two points $X$ and $Y$ which move on the curve. The plane determined by these three points approaches a fixed plane as $X$ and $Y$ approach the point $\alpha(t)$. This plane is called the *osculating plane*.

They also determine a unique circle passing through all three points, and these circles approach a fixed circle as $X$ and $Y$ get closer to $\alpha(t)$. This is the *circle of curvature*.

It is an easy exercise to check that these are compatible with the usual definitions. With this in mind the problem reduces to showing that projecting the curve to the osculating plane at $\alpha(t)$ does not change the osculating circle. This should be obvious once phrased as follows:
Given a sequence of triangles whose limit is a single point, the limit of their circumcircles is the same as the limit of their circumellipses provided the eccentricity of these ellipses goes to zero.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, so basically this projection is onto the plane tn of alpha?

Comment: Ok, I think I have got an answer.
 let's assume that the osculating circle of $\alpha$, is given by the equation :
$$x^2(s)+y^2(s)=\frac{1}{k^2}$$

Now under the projection of $\pi$ onto the osculatin plane we get $$\pi\circ \alpha(s)=(x(s),y(s),0)$$, so we get:
$$ |\pi\circ\alpha(s)|^2 =\frac{1}{k^2}$$
So upto a sign the curvatures of both $\alpha$ and $\pi\circ\alpha$, now they have the same sign cause the orientation of both of these curves are the same.

Does it need anymore tweaking?

Answer (score 1):

Although the geometric intuition given in the other response is amazing. I encountered the same problem and solved it in two (analytic) ways:

1. We know that the Osculating Plane in $t\in I$ is the set of points $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x=\alpha(t)+r_1\hat{t}(t)+r_2\hat{n}(t)$ where $\hat{t}(t)=\frac{\alpha'(t)}{\|\alpha'(t)\|}$,$\hat{n}(t)=\frac{\alpha''(t)}{\|\alpha''(t)\|}$ and $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

   Now for every $y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ define the projection of $x$ over $y$ to be $P_{y}(x):=\frac{x\cdot y}{\|y\|^2}y$.

   To answer your question: the projection of a vector $x$ over a plane $\pi_{_\mathcal{P}}(x)$ is obtained by computing the linear combination of the projection of $x$ to each of the spanning vectors of the plane, in this case: $\pi_{_\mathcal{P}}(x)=P_{\hat{n}(t)}(x)+P_{\hat{t}(t)}(x)=[x\cdot\hat{n}(t)]\hat{n}(t)+[x\cdot\hat{t}(t)]\hat{t}(t)$.

   Finally, if we compose $\pi_{_\mathcal{P}}\circ\alpha$, derivate that function two times and evaluate in $t$ (to get its curvature) we get the desired result.
2. Another way to get the proyection of a point $u\in\mathbb{R}^3$ over the plane $\mathcal{P}$ is to remember that a plane is the geometric space whose points $x=(x,y,z)$ satisfy that $ax+by+cz+d=0$ where the vector $n=(a,b,c)$ is normal to the plane and $n\cdot x_0=-d$ for some $x_0\in\mathcal{P}$. If you consider the line "with foot" in $u$ and spanned by $n$, i.e., $\mathcal{L}=\{u+tn|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, that line should intersect the plane $\mathcal{P}$ in the point $\pi_{_\mathcal{P}}(u)$. Doing some computations you should get that:
   $$\pi_{_\mathcal{P}}(u)=u+t_0n=u-P_{n}(u)-P_n(x_0)$$
   Proceding in the same way as in 1. using $\hat{b}(t)=\hat{n}(t)\times\hat{t}(t)$ as the vector normal to $\mathcal{P}$ should give the same result.